# Undefined control sequence \bibfont ->\bibliofont\footnotesize when using biblatex with acm bbx styles

Tags: biblatex, acmart

I am finding a really weird error when generating my PDF file with xelatex and using *any* ACM style with Biblatex and any backend (I tried biber, bibtex and natbib).

This is my simple example to reproduce:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,bibliography=totoc,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,dateabbrev=false,style=acmauthoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title{Example}

\begin{document}

\lipsum \cite{5952536}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(You can try with any reference in your `bib` file, it does not matter). This is what I am using to compile my document:

```
latexmk -xelatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf -outdir=output main.tex
```

The error I am getting is weird:

```
output/main.bbl:69: Undefined control sequence.
\bibfont ->\bibliofont 
                       \footnotesize 
l.69     \endentry
                  
) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
./main.tex:12: Undefined control sequence.
\bibfont ->\bibliofont 
                       \footnotesize 
l.12 \end
         {document}
./main.tex:12: Undefined control sequence.
\bibfont ->\bibliofont 
                       \footnotesize 
l.12 \end
         {document}
[2] (output/main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.
```

Interestingly the PDF file is generated at the end without problems (except the abrupt ending by the error when generating). If I change the style to something else, for example `numeric` no error when generating is shown.

Any idea what is happening? My current guess is that `acm` styles are designed to be used with `acmart` but I want to continue using KOMA article (this is for my thesis, not an ACM article).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\bibliofont` is not available in all document classes. It is defined by the AMS classes (`amsart`, `amsbook`, `amsproc`) and therefore also available in `acmart`, because `acmart` is based on `amsart`.

If you are using a class that does not define `\bibliofont`, you can add something like

```
\newcommand{\bibliofont}{\footnotesize}
```

to your preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,bibliography=totoc,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=acmauthoryear, dateabbrev=false,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand{\bibliofont}{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Working bibliography]

I don't think that `sortin=none,` makes sense with an author-year style, so I have removed that option.

Comment: Weirdly, the ACM `biblatex` styles do `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\bibliofont\footnotesize}`, so override any size setting from the `\bibliofont` command. Maybe that is something to take up with the style developers.

Comment: Thanks @moewe! that helped and now it works as expected.